# Make a list of code paths mutually exclusive

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction

This is more a general question, not specific to a language.
Basically: how can I convert a list of 1-deep code paths, i.e. a list of if conditions, to a list of mutually exclusive if conditions? I.e. is there a family of algorithms to do that? I have the feeling this is a common problem in compilers.

Let's constrain the problem. We have a very simple language.

- integer variables
- an if/else condition with two binary operators == and !=
- execution happens from top to bottom
- there are no side effects: below if b = 1 and then b = 2, we can remove the first assignment

Example:

```
if a == 1 { b = 1 }
if a == 2 { b = 2 }
if a != 3 { b = 2 }
if a == 4 { b = 3 }
```

would be converted to e.g.:

```
if a == 4 { b = 3 }
else if a != 3 { b = 2 }
```

If that is solved, it would get more challenging with supporting <, >, &, |.

Comment: Are those two really equivalent? Wouldn't `b` retain its previous value if `a` is 3 (whereas it'd become 3 in the converted version)?

Comment: @sepp2k right! fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. If (a != 3) b→2. If (a==4), well, then it is "!=3", so b→2. But you write if (a==4) b→3. So the rules are contradicting each other. Now, if (a == 4) beats (a != 3), then later rules beat former rules?

Comment: It's like a program: executed from top to bottom. I'll update the question.

Comment: In my experience any technical problem can be solved by throwing three-letter acronyms at it until it goes away. In this case SSA and SMT sound like the right candidates. Note though that it's not that common for SMT solvers to be used in compilers' optimization stages due to their run time cost. Neither gcc nor clang will optimize your example, but they will optimize if you replace `a != 3` with `a != 2` (presumably because they detect that as the negation of the previous if and then realize on their own that it's an if-else, superseding the previous if's assignments one way or another).

Comment: @sepp2k cool, thank you, that were the terms I was looking for! That family can help solving the subproblem of determining mutual exclusiveness of (sub-)conditions.

Comment: @sepp2k: I feel that your comment is just enough of being an answer.  Please post it as such and let bobbel accept it, so SO can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research. So there are two steps:

1. detecting mutual exclusiveness
2. make two non-mutually exclusive conditions mutually exclusive

ad 1. Detecting mutual exclusiveness can be done using SAT solvers as sepp2k already said. Not sure how they work internally, but a colleague gave the hint of using the idea of abstraction interpretation with lattices as values.

ad 2. In a naive approach, for two non-mutually exclusive code paths A and B, we simply replace the two with conditions A & B, A & ~B and ~A & B.